# Camera.setMode sets small resolution

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, camera

I have a Lenovo tablet with Windows 8.1 with front and rear cameras.
The rear camera is IMX175 and should supports 3280*2464 pixels.

When I call setMode with those dimensions I never got them back (in Camera.width/height) but some lower numbers.

In IE (11) I get 1280*960

In Chrome I get 1920*1440

I tried to change the frame rate to several options, set the stage.quality to StageQuality.BEST.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons between the cam-specifications, flash-player and browsers which affect the final maximal resolution. I dont think, you'll able to attach the full (foto)resolution of the IMX175 to a video-object...
In the past I wrote this script to detect the real possible resolutions of webcams in flash.

```
function testCams():void
{
    var camNames:Array = Camera.names;

    for (var i:int; i< camNames.length; i++)
    {
        var camName:String = camNames[i];
        trace(camName,"\n================================");

        var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(i.toString());
        cam.setMode(8000,6000,1);
        var camMaxWidth:Number = cam.width;
        var camMaxHeight:Number = cam.width;
        trace("Maxima w,h: ",camMaxWidth,camMaxHeight);
        //4:3
        cam.setMode(camMaxWidth,camMaxWidth/4*3, 100);
        trace("Maximum 4:3 w,h: ",cam.width,cam.height);
        //16:9
        cam.setMode(camMaxWidth,camMaxWidth/16*9, 100);
        trace("Maximum 16:9 w,h: ",cam.width,cam.height);

        trace("Maximum fps: ",cam.fps);
    }
}

testCams();
```

Test your cams and look what mode is possible. Greetings.

Comment: Thanks Andre. If that's the case I'm in problem since 1M pixel is really low nowadays. Do you have any source for how the final resolution is calculated, or you did "trial and error" method to know that?

Comment: No I havent any source. Only the experience that different cams react in different ways. Which resolution did my little test calculate?

Comment: The highest number I got was around 1280 (on IE9), and it is pretty bad... Thanks for your help Andre!