# Take a picture in Flash Player directly from camera (not via video capturing)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, camera

I would like to let the user taking a picture via web app.
I know the class **flash.media.Camera** but It doesn't take a picture directly, but you can capture an image from that - this kind of solution is not suitable for my needs since the resolution is pretty low.

I know the class **flash.media.CameraUI** but it is only works for the Air Runtime.

I'll appreciate to hear about an alternative.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> this kind of solution is not suitable for my needs since the resolution is pretty low.

You should set the apropriate resolution then.
[`Camera`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html) has a method [`setMode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setMode%28%29) for that:

```
public function setMode(width:int, height:int, fps:Number, favorArea:Boolean = true):void
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know that but the resolution is too low, I posted some other question regarding that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984343/camera-setmode-sets-small-resolution